# Recyclerview in Fragments, skipping layout no adapter attached

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-studio-3.0

I'm trying to setup a Recyclerview but keep on getting errors on the initRecycleView() that says No Adapter Attached Skipping Layout.

I've tried calling a new constructor for the RecyclerView

`RecyclerView recyclerView = new RecyclerView(getContext());`

This will result skipping layout, but if i delete that and try this

`RecyclerView recyclerView = getView().findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);`

This will result invoke virtual method null object reference

```java
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "HomeFragment";

    //Vars
    private ArrayList<String> mImage = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> mTitle = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> mDesc = new ArrayList<>();

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: started");

        initBitmapImages();
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    }

    private void initBitmapImages(){
        Log.d(TAG, "initBitmapImages: preparing bitmaps");

        mImage.add("https://i.redd.it/j6myfqglup501.jpg");
        mTitle.add("Foto 1");
        mDesc.add("This is foto 1");

        mImage.add("https://i.redd.it/j6myfqglup501.jpg");
        mTitle.add("Foto 2");
        mDesc.add("This is foto 2");

        mImage.add("https://i.redd.it/j6myfqglup501.jpg");
        mTitle.add("Foto 3");
        mDesc.add("This is foto 3");

        mImage.add("https://i.redd.it/j6myfqglup501.jpg");
        mTitle.add("Foto 4");
        mDesc.add("This is foto 4");

        mImage.add("https://i.redd.it/j6myfqglup501.jpg");
        mTitle.add("Foto 5");
        mDesc.add("This is foto 5");

        mImage.add("https://i.redd.it/j6myfqglup501.jpg");
        mTitle.add("Foto 6");
        mDesc.add("This is foto 6");

        mImage.add("https://i.redd.it/j6myfqglup501.jpg");
        mTitle.add("Foto 7");
        mDesc.add("This is foto 7");

        mImage.add("https://i.redd.it/j6myfqglup501.jpg");
        mTitle.add("Foto 8");
        mDesc.add("This is foto 8");

        initRecyclerView();
    }

    private void initRecyclerView(){
        Log.d(TAG, "initRecyclerView: init recyclerView");

         RecyclerView recyclerView = getView().findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(mImage,mTitle,mDesc,getContext());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    }
}
```

the actual output i expect is that in the layout i could output a recycleview that i created :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this might help

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "HomeFragment";

    //Vars
    private ArrayList<String> mImage = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> mTitle = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> mDesc = new ArrayList<>();

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // initialize container view
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        // pass container view to bitmap images so that will use to initialize recyclerView
        initBitmapImages(view);

        return view;
    }



    private void initBitmapImages(View view){
        Log.d(TAG, "initBitmapImages: preparing bitmaps");

        mImage.add("https://i.redd.it/j6myfqglup501.jpg");
        mTitle.add("Foto 1");
        mDesc.add("This is foto 1");

        mImage.add("https://i.redd.it/j6myfqglup501.jpg");
        mTitle.add("Foto 2");
        mDesc.add("This is foto 2");

        mImage.add("https://i.redd.it/j6myfqglup501.jpg");
        mTitle.add("Foto 3");
        mDesc.add("This is foto 3");

        mImage.add("https://i.redd.it/j6myfqglup501.jpg");
        mTitle.add("Foto 4");
        mDesc.add("This is foto 4");

        mImage.add("https://i.redd.it/j6myfqglup501.jpg");
        mTitle.add("Foto 5");
        mDesc.add("This is foto 5");

        mImage.add("https://i.redd.it/j6myfqglup501.jpg");
        mTitle.add("Foto 6");
        mDesc.add("This is foto 6");

        mImage.add("https://i.redd.it/j6myfqglup501.jpg");
        mTitle.add("Foto 7");
        mDesc.add("This is foto 7");

        mImage.add("https://i.redd.it/j6myfqglup501.jpg");
        mTitle.add("Foto 8");
        mDesc.add("This is foto 8");

        // container view uses to initialize recycle view
        initRecyclerView(view);
    }
    private void initRecyclerView(View view){
        Log.d(TAG, "initRecyclerView: init recyclerView");

        // Initialize recycle view which exist in parent container view so it found and initialize 
        RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(mImage,mTitle,mDesc,getContext());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks if it helps. Actually **findViewById** needs the view to search in so in previous code, It didn't find the recycle view so I changed to code and provide fragment view to **findViewById** so it will find in it and initialize it

Comment: I have updated my answer with some explanation in comments. I tried to explain might help